# Python getting image folder lat and lon to df

Tags: python, pandas, jpeg

I tried to build a code in python to go over all photos in folder and get the exif info (only the date and the GPS info are relevant) .
I found a code online but it gives me an error.
code :

```
def find_images(image_dir, extensions=None):
    default_extensions = ('jpg', 'jpeg')
    if extensions is None:
        extensions = default_extensions
    elif isinstance(extensions, str):
        extensions = (extensions,)
    for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(image_dir):
        for filename in filenames:
#             print(filename, filename.split('.', 1))
            if filename.split('.', 1)[-1].lower() in extensions:
                yield os.path.join(root, filename)
            
def process_exif_data(image):
    decoded_exif = {}
    with Image.open(image) as image_file:
        exif_data = image_file._getexif()
        if exif_data is None:
            return None
        for tag, value in exif_data.items():
            decoded = TAGS.get(tag, tag)
            if decoded == "GPSInfo":
                decoded_exif.update(decode_gps_data(value))
            else:
                decoded_exif[decoded] = value

    # This could be done with a dict comprehension and a ternary expression too
    return decoded_exif
    

def decode_gps_data(info):
    gps_tags = {GPSTAGS.get(k, k): v for k, v in value.items}

    lat, long = get_coordinates(gps_tags)
    gps_tags['lat'] = lat
    gps_tags['lon'] = lon

    return gps_tags

def get_coordinates(gps_tags):
    coords = {'Latitude': 'N', 'Longitude': 'E'}
    for coord, nominal_ref in coords.items():
        c = gps_tags.get("GPS%s" % coord, None)
        c_ref = gps_tags.get("GPS%sRef" % coord, None)

        if c and c_ref:
            yield _convert_to_degrees(c, c_ref, nominal_ref)
        else:
            yield None
            
def _convert_to_degrees(value, ref, nominal_ref=None):
    if nominal_ref is None:
        nominal_ref = ('N', 'E',)
    elif isinstance(nom, str):
        nominal_ref = (nominal_ref, )
    ref = 1 if ref in nominal_ref else -1
    return ref * sum(float(v[0]) / float(v[1]) / 60 ** i for i, v in enumerate(value))
                        
def extract_important_data(image_data, important_datalabels=('lat', 'lon', 'DateTimeOriginal')):
    if image_data is None:
        return None
    return {key: image_data.get(key, None) for key in important_datalabels}
                        
def extract_info(images, important_datalabels=('lat', 'lon', 'DateTimeOriginal')):
    for image_path in images:
        print(image_path)
        exif_data = process_exif_data(image_path)
        important_data = extract_important_data(exif_data)
        if important_data:
            yield image_path, important_data
                        
def get_photos_info(image_dir, filename=None, important_datalabels=('lat', 'lon', 'DateTimeOriginal')):
    if image_dir is None:
        image_dir='.'

    images = find_images(image_dir)
    info = extract_info(imgs, important_datalabels=important_datalabels)
    result_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = important_datalabels)
    for image_path, item in info:
        result_df.loc[image_path] = item
    if 'DateTimeOriginal' in important_datalabels:
        date_format = '%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S'
        result_df['DateTimeOriginal'] = pd.to_datetime(result_df['DateTimeOriginal'], format=date_format)

    if filename:
        result_df.to_excel(filename)

    return result_df

empty_df = pd.DataFrame
empty_df = get_photos_info(r"C:\Users\dor h\OneDrive\Desktop\study\Final project")
```

error :

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-0aaf3d855413> in <module>
    123 
    124 empty_df = pd.DataFrame
--> 125 empty_df = get_photos_info(r"C:\Users\dor h\OneDrive\Desktop\study\Final project")
    126 # print(empty_df)

<ipython-input-32-0aaf3d855413> in get_photos_info(image_dir, filename, important_datalabels)
    111     info = extract_info(imgs, important_datalabels=important_datalabels)
    112     result_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = important_datalabels)
--> 113     for image_path, item in info:
    114         result_df.loc[image_path] = item
    115     if 'DateTimeOriginal' in important_datalabels:

<ipython-input-32-0aaf3d855413> in extract_info(images, important_datalabels)
     99     for image_path in images:
    100         print(image_path)
--> 101         exif_data = process_exif_data(image_path)
    102         important_data = extract_important_data(exif_data)
    103         if important_data:

<ipython-input-32-0aaf3d855413> in process_exif_data(image)
     48 def process_exif_data(image):
     49     decoded_exif = {}
---> 50     with Image.open(image) as image_file:
     51         exif_data = image_file._getexif()
     52         if exif_data is None:

D:\paython\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in open(fp, mode)
   2816         exclusive_fp = True
   2817 
-> 2818     prefix = fp.read(16)
   2819 
   2820     preinit()

AttributeError: 'JpegImageFile' object has no attribute 'read'
```

I read somewhere that the problem is I'm trying to open an already open jpg file but I don't see where I'm doing so also I don't know how to solve that.

tnx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that in the line `info = extract_info(imgs, important_datalabels=important_datalabels)`, `imgs` is a typo, and should instead be `images`.

Why this gives you the specific error mode you are seeing depends on what `imgs` is. The variable `imgs` must be defined somewhere in your notebook, otherwise your code would raise a NameError. `imgs` is probably a list or iterator containing some kind of object that `Image.open()` doesn't expect; this would cause it to fail when it tries to use the object's `read` method.